# MUI System - Styled component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components, dnd-kit

I have created MyComponent( called 'InnerContainer' ) by using MUI system; styled-component. But onClick under the styled component is not working. It is working outside 'InnerContainer' but not working inside 'InnerContainer'. Don't know the reason.. please help me why it's not working.

```
import { useSortable } from "@dnd-kit/sortable";
import { CSS } from "@dnd-kit/utilities";
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
// import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";

function DraggableBox(props) {
  const { attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform, transition } =
    useSortable({ id: props.id });

  // console.log("props", props);

  const outerContainer = {
    transform: CSS.Transform.toString(transform),
    transition,
    backgroundColor: props.color,
    width: "20%",
    height: "25%",
    display: "inline-block",
  };
  
  
  const InnerContainer = styled("div")({
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "end",
    fontWeight: "600",
    "&:hover svg": {
      color: "white",
      transform: "scale(1.3)",
      transition: "0.5s",
    },
    " .inBoxName": {
      marginLeft: "0.5rem",
    },
    " .inBoxTrash": {
      marginRight: "0.5rem",
    },
  });

  return (
    <div style={outerContainer} ref={setNodeRef} {...attributes} {...listeners}>
      <InnerContainer>
        <div className="inBoxName">{props.name}</div>
        <div className="inBoxTrash">
          <DeleteIcon onClick={() => props.removeColorBox(props.id)} />
        </div>
      </InnerContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DraggableBox;
```

Comment: Verify that the DeleteIcon component is correctly styled and does not have any conflicting styles that may prevent the click event from being triggered.

Comment: DeleteIcon component has no style. It's from MUI and replaced it with a regular html button but it didn't work :( thank you for your comment though!